# Alcatel X500 datacard won't recognize on ubuntu 12.04 using xhci

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, usb-modem, xhci-hcd

I have two laptops running ubuntu 12.04 with the latest updates. One is a gateway ID79C and the other is an ASUS SM56CM. All I needed to do to get connected on the gateway was to add

```
usbserial
option
```

to /etc/modules.

I did the same thing on the asus but it seems not to be recognizing and adding the option lines in dmesg.

Relevant dmesg output:

Gateway:

```
[469749.811939] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 52 using ehci_hcd
[469750.267397] scsi52 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[469751.272023] scsi 52:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ALCATEL  Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[469751.272742] scsi 52:0:0:1: CD-ROM            ALCATEL  Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[469751.274511] sd 52:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[469751.280206] sr1: scsi-1 drive
[469751.280509] sr 52:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[469751.280714] sr 52:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 5
[469751.281166] sd 52:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[469751.403557] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 52
[469751.733967] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 53 using ehci_hcd
[469752.189850] option 2-1.2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[469752.190072] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[469752.190267] option 2-1.2:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[469752.190482] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[469752.190831] option 2-1.2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[469752.190984] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[469752.191243] option 2-1.2:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[469752.191449] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[469752.191875] scsi53 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.4
[469752.192126] option 2-1.2:1.5: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[469752.192331] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
[469752.192520] option 2-1.2:1.6: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[469752.192656] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB5
[469753.189991] scsi 53:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ALCATEL  Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[469753.191413] sd 53:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[469753.194091] sd 53:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Asus:

```
[55094.440196] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[55094.459739] usb 3-2: ep 0x1 - rounding interval to 32768 microframes, ep desc says 0 microframes
[55094.459752] usb 3-2: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 32768 microframes, ep desc says 0 microframes
[55094.856171] scsi8 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
[55095.855573] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ALCATEL  Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[55095.856306] scsi 8:0:0:1: CD-ROM            ALCATEL  Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[55095.858282] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[55095.860853] sr1: scsi-1 drive
[55095.861136] sr 8:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[55095.861322] sr 8:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 5
[55095.864531] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

The only difference that I can see is that the asus is using xhci_hcd (usb 3.0) vs ehci_hcd(usb 2.0) on the gateway.

I have also tried manually switching with usb_modeswitch but it says it can't find previous drivers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To add some more information:

    lsmod | grep option
    option                 30115  0 
    usb_wwan               20491  1 option
    usbserial              47077  2 option,usb_wwan
option and usbserial are present

Answer (score 1):

I got it working on the ASUS by going into the bios and disabling xhci. SO it is definitely something wrong with the xhci functionality in conjunction with usb_modeswitch/option. So no usb 3.0 love for me until this issue is sorted out :(

ASUS dmesg output:

```
[  199.903558] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[  200.362841] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[  200.363104] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[  200.363319] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  200.363326] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[  200.368504] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  201.362896] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ALCATEL  Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  201.363623] scsi 6:0:0:1: CD-ROM            ALCATEL  Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  201.365534] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  201.367932] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  201.372133] sr1: scsi-1 drive
[  201.373843] sr 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[  201.374064] sr 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 5
[  201.544644] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  201.808647] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[  202.264289] option 2-1.2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  202.264630] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  202.264915] option 2-1.2:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  202.265222] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[  202.265512] option 2-1.2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  202.265834] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[  202.266098] option 2-1.2:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  202.266355] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[  202.266582] option 2-1.2:1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  202.266817] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
[  202.267021] option 2-1.2:1.5: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  202.267252] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB5
[  202.267460] option 2-1.2:1.6: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[  202.267629] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB6
[  272.095114] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  272.095476] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[  272.095523] option 2-1.2:1.0: device disconnected
[  272.096378] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
[  272.096486] option 2-1.2:1.1: device disconnected
[  272.097240] option1 ttyUSB2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
[  272.097377] option 2-1.2:1.2: device disconnected
[  272.098003] option1 ttyUSB3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB3
[  272.098083] option 2-1.2:1.3: device disconnected
[  272.098637] option1 ttyUSB4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB4
[  272.098716] option 2-1.2:1.4: device disconnected
[  272.098957] option: option_instat_callback: error -108
[  272.099359] option1 ttyUSB5: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB5
[  272.099406] option 2-1.2:1.5: device disconnected
[  272.099629] option: option_instat_callback: error -108
[  272.099895] option1 ttyUSB6: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB6
[  272.099908] option 2-1.2:1.6: device disconnected
```